how to open a web url in a selected display. ie. Firefox on Display 0 and 2nd firefox on display 1 at startup?
Can someone direct me to learn how to open a web url in a selected display. ie. Firefox on Display 0 and 2nd Firefox on display 1? needs to run at startup on a thin Client. Thanks.
current process is to move windows after luanching. it fails to work as the window title has changed often.

Actually, there isn't a built-in way to do this directly from a web page because security restrictions prevent websites from controlling your computer.  However, we have a couple of workarounds:
you can use Magic Script.
You can use JavaScript and Node.js If you know them already.
